# Redux Store Changing Without Subscription Call or Reducer Log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm running into an issue where redux is corrupting read only data in the store.

I setup a subscription just to test and while it works when I change fields, it is not called when the store corrupts itself. I also included log messages in the action and reducer that fire when the field is initialized but not when the field is corrupted. Any ideas where to look to solve this? I tried updating redux but it was unhelpful.

Console Output: The corruption can be seen where the fifth item in the field changes.

```
$r.store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($r.store.getState())))
});
<Removed the subscribe printing the store multiple times to test with no corruption>
    $r.store.getState().tdValues
{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}}
1: {product: "Test", alias: "PR", value: "D1"}
2: {product: "Test", alias: "PR", value: "D2"}
3: {product: "Test", alias: "DR", value: "A1"}
4: {product: "Test", alias: "DR", value: "A2"}
5: {product: "Test", alias: "PR", value: "D3"}
6: {product: "Test", alias: "PR", value: "D4"}
__proto__: Object
TDData.js:15 tdValues1:  
{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}}
TDData.js:31 tdValues2:  
{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}}
TDData.js:159 multiLevelTDValues: 
{AAZERCK: {…}}
$r.store.getState().trimDescriptorValues
{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}}
1: {product: "Test", alias: "PR", value: "D1"}
2: {product: "Test", alias: "PR", value: "D2"}
3: {product: "Test", alias: "DR", value: "A1"}
4: {product: "Test", alias: "DR", value: "A2"}
5: {product: "Test", alias: "PR", value: "D4"}
6: {product: "Test", alias: "PR", value: "D4"}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: can you reproduce the issue on jfiddle ?